# What is true when Big O is of another function

Tags: big-o

Imagine that we have three functions *f(n)*, *g(n)* and *h(n)* and that ***f(n) = O(g(n))***

If *g(n)* = (1/5)*h(n)* is it possible that ***f(n) = O(h(n))***?

Why is it possible / not possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because comp.sci homework is not about (applied) programming.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [formal Definition of big-O](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). You should understand what 1/5 represents. Hint: It is clearly a constant. I will not provide a formal proof as I guess is part of this homework, but you may try to show equality in big-O between these functions.